# The method set(int, int) in the type Calendar is not applicable for the arguments (int, String)

Tags: java, datetime, compiler-errors, arguments, java.util.calendar

Java code to create date from given day of week, week of month, month and year as input. Example- if the iputs are as below:

> day-Monday, month-july, week-1, year-2018,

then output should be-02/07/2018.

Below is the code used:

```
        System.out.println("Enter a year,month,week,day:");
        int year = Integer.parseInt(obj.nextLine());
        int month = Integer.parseInt(obj.nextLine());
        int week = Integer.parseInt(obj.nextLine());
        String day = obj.nextLine();

        String date;

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy/MM/dd");

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year); // set the year
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1); // set the month
        cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, week);

        //***error in the below line********
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,day);

        date=dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("Result:" +date);
```

The marked line won’t compile. Why not? How should I fix it?

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried thus far, where are you stuck? Without showing any effort on your own we probably won't be able to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could [edit], rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: added the code, unable to get the date if I specify the day of the week. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the code, it helps. The date and time classes you are using, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`, are long outdated and poorly designed. I recommend you throw them over your shoulder and instead use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bit you seem to be missing is that when the user enters for example “Monday”, you need to convert this string into something that Java can understand as a day of week. This is done through *parsing*. Fortunately using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, it is not so hard (when you know how). This is what we use the `dowFormatter` for in the following code (dow for day of week):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");

    DateTimeFormatter dowFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE", Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));
    DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from(dowFormatter.parse(day));

    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY));

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, 15)
            .with(dow)
            .with(wf.weekOfMonth(), week);
    System.out.println("Result: " + date.format(dateFormatter));
```

Now when I enter 2018, 7, 1 and Monday, I get:

> Result: 2018/07/02

If you want to control in which language the user should enter the day of week, pass the appropriate locale to the formatter (instead of `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)`). If you want it to work in English only, you may use the shorter `DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.valueOf(day.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));`, but it’s a bit of a hack.

If you want to control the week scheme used, pass the appropriate locale to `WeekFields.of()` or just specify `WeekFields.ISO` or `WeekFields.SUNDAY_START`.

I recommend that you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are long outdated. `java.time` is much nicer to work with.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.